# Find Jaccard similarity between multiple list

Tags: python, for-loop

Let's say I have 3 list:

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l2 = ["c", "e", "f"]
l3 = ["c", "b", "a"]
```

For Jaccard similarity, I'm using the following function:

```
def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))
    union = (len(set(list1)) + len(set(list2))) - intersection
    return float(intersection) / union
```

How can I calculate the Jaccard similarity for all combinations, that is:

```
(l1,l1), (l1,l2), (l1, l3)
(l2,l1), (l2,l2), (l2, l3) 
(l3,l1), (l3,l2), (l3, l3)
```

I want to avoid doing this manually for each pair of lists. Also, the final output needs to be a `3x3` matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the `list` from `list(set(...))` in your original function. Also no need to cast `intersection` to a `float` as you are using the "float division operator":

```
def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(set(list1).intersection(list2))
    union = (len(set(list1)) + len(set(list2))) - intersection
    return intersection / union
```

You can use `product` from the `itertools` module to generate pairs of lists, and consume them using `starmap` with your function:

```
from itertools import product, starmap

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['c', 'e', 'f']
l3 = ['c', 'b', 'a']

inputs = product([l1, l2, l3], [l1, l2, l3])

result = list(starmap(jaccard_similarity, inputs))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0]
```

Next, to create a matrix you can take a look at the `grouper` recipe from the documentation of `itertools`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Here's a simplified example of the `grouper` function:

```
def group_three(it):
    iterators = [iter(it)] * 3
    return zip(*iterators)

print(list(group_three(result)))
```

Output:

```
[(1.0, 0.2, 1.0), (0.2, 1.0, 0.2), (1.0, 0.2, 1.0)]
```